# Activity cannot be transfered into a onclicklistener

Tags: java, android

I made one of the simplest programs that creates a login page, however, I cannot add an `OnClickListener` to my button, and I do not know why. I'm really new to Android Studio and have no idea what to do. When I hover over the error it says `"In View cannot be applied"`.

I've tried these bits of code found on the internet, but the error doesn't leave, and the machine says that the `@Override` does not override what's above.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacher_in_j);

    regist1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnregister1);
    regist1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent teachtoregist = new Intent(TeacherInJ.this, TeacherRegisterInJ.class);
            startActivity(teachtoregist);
        }
    });

    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);


    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnlogin:
            //Start activity one
            break;
```

Comment: can you show your Logcat error fully?

Comment: Please post your full activity code.

Comment: Add implements View.OnClickListener in in your Activity

Answer (score 2):

> When I hover over the error it says "In View cannot be applied".
>
> I've tried these bits of code found on the internet, but the error doesn't leave, and the machine says that the @override does not override what's above.

Both the above problems are because you didn't add the `implements` keyword to your Activity. You need to add it so the Activity can be regarded as `OnClickListener` interface by the button.

You need to do something like this (See the comments inside the code):

```
// see below the implements View.OnClickListener line that
// need to be added so the Activitiy can be regarded as the listener.
public class TeacherInJ extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
  ...

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacher_in_j);

        ...

        // now you can use this as the listener. It's because you have
        // set the current Activity class as the View.OnClickListener
        // this is refer to current Activity object.
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // Now you can add the @Override to the onClick method from
    // the View.OnClickListener.
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnlogin:
          //Start activity one
          break;
      }
    }
}
```